# How to make Inner Join to work on TypeORM?

Tags: typeorm

I'm trying to build a simple query on TypeORM but I'm not getting the entire data using INNER JOIN. What am I doing wrong?

The SQL query runs perfectly but the typeorm one just returns me the data for the 'watcher' table.

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT *
FROM watcher w
INNER JOIN user
ON w.userId = user.id;
```

**TypeORM**

```
async getSystemWideWatchers(): Promise<any[]> {
    const query = this.createQueryBuilder('watcher');
    const result = await query.innerJoin('user', 'u', 'watcher.userId = u.id').getMany();
    console.log(result)
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

TypeORM has a method called `innerJoinAndSelect`. You use plain `innerJoin`. That is why user table is not selected from.

Once you change that part to `innerJoinAndSelect`, watch table will be selected from. However, `getMany` and `getOne` returns objects with your Entity type. Therefore, if your Entity types do not have the relationships between User and Watcher tables, selected columns will not be included in the returned object.

Before I show you how to add these relations, I want to mention that you have the option to use `getRawMany` function to get all selected columns, but I don't recommend using it, since relationships are much tidier (no raw column names, you get arrays of Entities corresponding to relationships) and in your case, there is no reason not to use relationships.

Now, the way I understand your database design, you have Users, and Users have Watchers. A Watcher watches only one User, and there may be multiple Watchers that watch the same user.

In this case, the relationship of User to Watcher is called "One to Many".

The relationship of Watcher to User is called "Many to One".

You need to specify this information in your Entity. Here is an example. Notice the `OneToMany` decorator.

```js
@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    userName: string;

    @OneToMany(type => Watcher, watcher => watcher.user)
    watchers: Watcher[];
}
```

Here is the corresponding Watcher Entity:

```js
@Entity()
export class Watcher {
    @PrimaryColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    watcherName: string;

    // we can omit this (and the join condition), if userId is a foreign key
    @Column()
    userId: number;

    @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.watchers)
    user: User;
}
```

Once you have these relationships, you can select a User, along with all their Watchers, or vice versa (select a Watcher with the User they watch).

Here is how you do both:

```js
// Select a user and all their watchers
const query = createQueryBuilder('user', 'u')
    .innerJoinAndSelect('u.watchers', 'w'); // 'w.userId = u.id' may be omitted
const result = await query.getMany();
```

(If you want to include users with no watchers, you use leftJoin instead of innerJoin, as you probably know.)

This is probably what you were initially trying to do:

```js
// Select a watcher and the user they watch
const query = createQueryBuilder('watcher', 'w')
    .innerJoinAndSelect('w.user', 'u'); // 'w.userId = u.id' may be omitted
const result = await query.getMany();
```

Comment: You probably don't have the necessary relations. I updated my answer. Could you check again?

Comment: Brother you got it! The entities are exactly how I had it. The problem was that I tried to join by using the `user.id` and `watcher.userId` instead of `watcher.user`. Thank you very very much! Happy new year!

Comment: Ah - you had the relationship but weren't using it... I'm happy it's fixed, happy new year to you too!

Comment: Great answer @Cem
I have follow up question, maybe you could help me ;)

The query you provided will return: `{ id: 1, userName: 'matt', watchers: [ { id: 1, watcherName: 'joe' } ] }`

What if I want to map this value, eg.`{ id: 1, userName: 'matt', watchers: ['joe'] }`

or from Watcher perspective, I would like to get: `{ id: 1, watcherName: 'joe', userName: 'matt' }`

Answer (score 12):

Just in case someone runs into another scenario. Adding to what Cem answered.
If there's no relationship defined in the database then you can do the following :

```
const query = createQueryBuilder('user', 'u')    
.innerJoinAndMapMany(
    'u.ObjectNameToMapDataOn',
    EntityName,// or 'tableName'
    'IAmAlias',
    'u.columnName= IAmAlias.columnName'
  )
```

similarly , innerJoinAndMapOne can be used. Depends on your case if you expect to have multiple records with joining table or single record.

Comment: Thank You that was really helpful

Answer (score 8):

if there isn't relations between the two tables, you will have to use `getRow()`.

`getOne()` and `getMany()` will return object with type of your repository, and so drop the data of the joined table

this example works for me:

```
this.userRepository
            .createQueryBuilder('user')
            .select(['user.username as username', 'o.orderTime as orderTime'])
            .where('user.id = :id', {id})
            .andWhere('o.callerId = :id', {id})
            .innerJoin(OrderEntity, 'o')
            .getRawMany()
```

Comment: Thanks! using `getRawMany()` worked for me instead of `getMany()`

Comment: For example:

 const res = await createQueryBuilder('profiles', 'profile')
    .select(['profile.*', 'user.name'])
    .where('profile.user.id = :userId', { userId })
    .innerJoin(User, 'user', 'user.id = :userId', { userId })
    .getRawMany();

Comment: Thanks mate getRawMany() worked , seems getMany only works when entity itself  have relations like oneToMany and manyToOne but my entities don't have any relations so raw worked

Answer (score 2):

For someone who only want to add `on` after join in typeorm.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM watcher w
INNER JOIN user
ON w.userId = user.id;
```

```js
this.userRepo
.createQueryBuilder("u")
.leftJoin(Watcher, "w", "u.id = w.userId");
```